# Zeros of regular functions on quasiprojective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Is it true that the set of zeros of a regular function on a quasiprojective variety $X$ is closed in $X$?

I have doubt about this because by definition, a closed subset of $X$ is the intersection of $X$ and a closed subset of projective space. A closed subset of the  projective space is by definition the zeros of a system of homogeneous polynomials. However, regular functions on a quasiprojective variety are not only polynomials.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quasiprojective variety can be covered by affine varieties and a subset of it is closed if its intersection with each element of the cover is closed. And for affine variety your question is obvious.

Comment: @danneks Thanks for your comment but I don't see how it works when I think of the example of the affine line minus one point. By "cover" do you mean that a quasiprojective variety is the union of affine varieties or it is a subset of the union of affine varieties?

Comment: By affine variety I mean an algebraic variety isomorphic to an affine variety. An affine line minus one point is an affine variety: it is isomorphic to the hyperbola $xy-1=0$. If you have a regular function on affine line minus one point, you can consider the induced function on the hyperbola, prove that its set of zeros is closed and use that isomorphism preserves closed subsets.

Comment: @danneks thanks! Now I get it.